# Texmaker Quickbuild with included .tex files

Tags: texmaker

I have a question about the Quickbuild in Texmaker.
I have included `.tex` files in the `main.tex` like:
`\input{Chapter1/Introduction}`

When I edit the included `tex`-file and want to Quickbuild my document errors appearing. I know I have to select the `main.tex` with all necessary commands like `\begin{document}` etc. and build it from there.
Is it possible to Quickbuild it from my included files to avoid jumping to my `main.tex`?

Comment: Go to your main file tab, -> Options -> Declare Current file as master.